# How to uninstall Pip and Tensorflow properly in my case

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, pip

I use pip3 to install packages on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine.

I wanted to upgrade pip3, but I typed `pip3 install --upgrade pip` so pip got installed. I didn't recognize it and installed Tensorflow. Now things are messed up.

How do I uninstall pip and Tensorflow in my case?

The following commands don't work because the respective packages could not be found:

- sudo apt-get remove pip
- sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow

Comment: `pip uninstall tensorflow`?

Comment: Thank you! Life can be so simple! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, by running `pip3 install --upgrade pip` command you will upgrade pip3 not pip.

For removing pip from the system, You can try `sudo apt-get remove python-pip` or `pip uninstall pip`.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove python-pip did not work and pip is still installed

Comment: What do you need exactly? pip is installed by default in Ubuntu. by doing 'pip3 install -- upgrade pip'  you can not install pip.

Comment: I want pip to get removed